# Rails 3 - Installation Problems...Could not find bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to install Rails 3 on a new MacBook Pro...

when trying to get my app going, I get the following error:

```
Could not find bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

When I run bundle install, I get the following:

```
...

Installing bcrypt-ruby (2.1.2) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Also... When I run rails -v it returns:

```
Could not find bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Comment: do you have XCode installed and upgraded up to the latest version? Without it you can't compile gems with native extensions. On my quite a new MB Pro it works without a glitches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem compiling the extension, most likely you are missing a C library or something like that. On my Mac it installed with no problem using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10.4.0] installed with RVM.

Can you try gem install bcrypt-ruby to get more debugging output?

Are you using ports or brew or something else?

Comment: Turns out I needed to install Xcode on the Mac. That fixed it.